Receive Postbacks through NSAdvertisingAttributionReportEndpoint with Node
I try to get the body of a postback with Node in Firebase Functions:
const app = require("express")();

app.post("/.well-known/skadnetwork/report-attribution/", function(req, res) {
  // Do the processing
  console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body));
  return res.sendStatus(200);
});

exports.skan = functions.https.onRequest(app);

As described in the Apple Docs, the postback is sent to the server by the endpoint NSAdvertisingAttributionReportEndpoint defined in xcode.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/configuring-an-advertised-app
I have to configure my server to accept HTTPS POST messages at the following well-known path:
https://example.com/.well-known/skadnetwork/report-attribution/

But I get nothing. How can I read the body of the well-known path? What I'm doing wrong? Maybe I misunderstand Apples description.
In the info.plist I defined the endpoint like this:
<key>NSAdvertisingAttributionReportEndpoint</key>
<string>https://us-central1-XXX.cloudfunctions.net/skan/</string>


You didn't say in your post, but it looks like you're using Firebase flavored Cloud Functions, as evidenced by your export:
exports.skan = functions.https.onRequest(app);

When you export like this, you are explicitly creating a URL endpoint that includes the name of the export as the first path component.  In your case, this is "skan".  When you deploy the function, you will probably see this in the output.  Unfortunately, it's not possible to change the full path of the URL endpoint to conform to the requirement that the path be exactly "/.well-known/skadnetwork/report-attribution/".
If you want to keep using Cloud Functions, along with Firebase, your only viable option here is to:

Use Firebase Hosting
Optionally connect a custom domain with it (if you can't accept the default hostname provided by Firebase)
Forward the required path to your function by Firebase Hosting configuration, which involves setting up a rewrite rule to direct the request to your function.

You should probably also consider not using express in this case, as it will complicate things unnecessarily.  Normal HTTP function receive a Request and Response object that are already compatible with express.

Thanks a lot, Doug. Let me summarize: I have to add a path "/.well-known/skadnetwork/report-attribution/" within Firebase Hosting, redirect there to my function and set the endpoint to my firebasehosting url including "/.well-known/skadnetwork/report-attribution/", right?

Sure, give it a try.

if I try to implement it without firebase hosting how could I redirect it from the "/.well-known/skadnetwork/report-attribution/" folder?
Will  work?
Can you show an alternative for a normal website / hosting? Thanks a lot!
